# Azure Active Directory API always shown forbidden message

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, azureportal

I am a beginner in using Azure Active Directory Implementation. I have a WEB API (.net core) with Azure Active Directory protection. I am trying to consume my WEB API through Postman, I know it needs an Auth2 token for consume web API. I already generate the auth2 token as per this [documentation link](https://www.bruttin.com/2017/11/21/azure-api-postman.html).

After generate the Auth2 token, add auth2 token in the header, like `Authorization: Bearer e....` but the result always shows like below image.

[image]

I am sure I will give the required permission in 'API Permission' section and 'Permission Type' is 'Delegated permissions' in Azure Portal.

Please see my startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(o =>
        {
            o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("default"));
        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddAuthorization(o =>
        {
            o.AddPolicy("default", policy =>
            {
                // Require the basic "Access app-name" claim by default
                policy.RequireClaim(DotNetCoreApiSample.Authorization.Constants.ScopeClaimType, "user_impersonation");
            });
        });

        services
            .AddAuthentication(o =>
            {
                o.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(o =>
            {
                o.Authority = Configuration["Authentication:Authority"];
                o.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    // Both App ID URI and client id are valid audiences in the access token
                    ValidAudiences = new List<string>
                    {
                    Configuration["Authentication:AppIdUri"],
                    Configuration["Authentication:ClientId"]
                    }
                };
            });
        // Add claims transformation to split the scope claim value
        services.AddSingleton<IClaimsTransformation, AzureAdScopeClaimTransformation>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        // Very important that this is before MVC (or anything that will require authentication)
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my test, once you have configured the policy, you can just can use the scope `{your resource url}/user_impersonation` to require access token then you can call your application with the access token. Otherwise, you will get 403 error. Please check your access token via the [link](https://jwt.io/) to ensure your scope

[image]

My test code is as below
1. `Stratup.cs`

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            var tenatId = Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"];
              services
             .AddAuthentication(o =>
             {
                 o.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
             })
             .AddJwtBearer(o =>
             {
                 o.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/v2.0";
                 o.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                 {




                     ValidIssuers = new[] {
                     "https://sts.windows.net/<tenant id>/",
                  "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/v2.0"



                     },
                    // Both App ID URI and client id are valid audiences in the access token
                    ValidAudiences = new List<string>
                     {
                    "<app id>",
                    "<app id url>"
                     }
                 };
             });
            services.AddAuthorization(o =>
            {
                o.AddPolicy("default", policy =>
                {
                  policy.RequireClaim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope", "user_impersonation");
                });
            });
        }



        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseAuthentication();



            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

2. Test

   a. get access token

   [image]
     [image]

   b. call the api

   [image]